# Ruby: How can I convert an array of data to hash and to json format?

Tags: ruby

I am very new to Ruby array and hash manipulation.

How can I do this simple transformation?

```
array = [#<struct id=1, car='red'>, #<struct id=2, car='yellow'>, #<struct id=3, car='green'>]
```

desired output in json:

```
[{id : 1, car : 'red'} , {id:2, car :'yellow'} ,{id:3 , car: "green"}]
```

Does anyone have any hints?

Comment: the desired output is not valid json. You mean an array? [...]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
array.map { |o| Hash[o.each_pair.to_a] }.to_json
```

Comment: You must `require 'json'` to get the `to_json` function.

Comment: You can also write ``.to_h`` instead.

Answer (score 7):

Convert array of `struct` objects into array of `hash`, then call `to_json`. You need to require `json` (ruby 1.9) in order to use the `to_json` method.

```
array.collect { |item| {:id => item.id, :car => item.car} }.to_json
```

Answer (score 2):

By default a Struct instance will be displayed as a string when encoding to json using the json ruby gem:

```
require 'json'
array = [#<struct id=1, car='red'>, #<struct id=2, car='yellow'>, #<struct id=3, car='green'>] # assuming real structure code in the array
puts array.to_json
```

prints

```
["#<struct id=1, car='red'>", "#<struct id=2, car='yellow'>", "#<struct id=3, car='green'>"]
```

This is obviously not what you want.

The next logical step is to make sure that your struct instances can be properly serialized to JSON, as well as created back from JSON.

To do this you can alter the declaration of your structure:

```
YourStruct = Struct.new(:id, :car)
class YourStruct
  def to_json(*a)
    {:id => self.id, :car => self.car}.to_json(*a)
  end

  def self.json_create(o)
    new(o['id'], o['car'])
  end
end
```

So you can now write the following:

```
a = [ YourStruct.new(1, 'toy'), YourStruct.new(2, 'test')]
puts a.to_json
```

which prints

```
[{"id": 1,"car":"toy"},{"id": 2,"car":"test"}]
```

and also deserialize from JSON:

```
YourStruct.json_create(JSON.parse('{"id": 1,"car":"toy"}'))
# => #<struct YourStruct id=1, car="toy">
```

Comment: very grateful for this.  i tried many other solutions and this was the first that worked... maybe someday I'll actually understand it.