# Jquery/Javascript remove double quotes form array value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, escaping

```
myArray = ["{url: '/delete', key: 71}", "{url: '/delete', key: 72}", "{url: '/delete', key: 73}", "{url: '/delete', key: 74}"]
```

I want to remove the `"` character that wrapped the object. Or escape from double quotes.

I have try this

```
myArray.replace(/"/g,"")
```

but it says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: myArray.replace is not a function
```

Anybody have the same experience? thank you

Comment: Where are you getting that data from? The format suggests it's supposed to be JSON, but the format is invalid.

Comment: Removing the quotes won't suddenly make the contents objects. If that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: I got the data from ruby array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** and **[`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)** to convert the string array to object array

> The eval() method evaluates JavaScript code represented as a string.

```js
var myArray = ["{url: '/delete', key: 71}", "{url: '/delete', key: 72}", "{url: '/delete', key: 73}", "{url: '/delete', key: 74}"];

myArray = myArray.map(function(v) {
  return eval('(' + v + ')');
});

document.write(JSON.stringify(myArray));
```

It's not a good approach, you can send data in valid json format. Which will be much safer than the above method. eg :  `["{\"url\": \"/delete\", \"key\": 71}", "{\"url\": \"/delete\", \"key\": 72}", "{\"url": \"/delete\", \"key\": 73}", "{\"url\": \"/delete\", \"key\": 74}"]`, in this case you can use `JSON.parse()` instead of `eval()`

In ruby you can convert the array to JSON string , refer [Ruby: How can I convert an array of data to hash and to json format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829473/ruby-how-can-i-convert-a-array-data-to-hash-and-to-json-format) , [Parsing a Ruby Array to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18127066/parsing-a-ruby-array-to-json) .

Comment: @kraf : it's not valid JSON